# Symfony 2 - Change entity field values of FormType

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have two OneToMany relationship between two entities : Serie ---> Episode and Episode ---> Musique which follow :

```
    class Serie{
     ........
        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Episode", mappedBy="serieId")
         * @ORM\OrderBy({"numeroE" = "ASC"})
         */
        private $episodes;
     ........
    }

    class Episode{
     ........
        /**
        * @var integer
        *
        * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Serie", inversedBy="episodes")
        * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="serie_id", referencedColumnName="id")
        */
       private $serieId;

       /**
        * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Musique", mappedBy="episodeId")
        * @ORM\OrderBy({"min" = "ASC", "sec" = "ASC"})
        */
       private $musiques;
    }

    class Musique{
       ........

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Episode", inversedBy="musiques")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="episode_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $episodeId;

       ........
    }
```

In my My\ContentBundle\Form\Type\MusiqueType, which represents a Musique Entity Form, I have :

```
class MusiqueType extends AbstractType{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('episodeId', 'entity', array(
                 'class' => 'MyContentBundle:Episode' ,
            )
            ->add('serieId', 'entity', array(
                 'class' => 'MyContentBundle:Serie' ,
                 'mapped' => false
            )
        ;
    }
}
```

In my view, i'd need to display the 'episodeId' field. However, as there are around one thousand Episodes in my database, i'd like to display in this field only the episodes that belong to the Serie selected.

I was going to use some ajax actions to do this, but i was wondering : is there was a simpler way to do it?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can be more specific in the generation of your form by adding a custom query to it :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
// ...

$builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
    },
));
```

Refer to the [entity Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) page of SF2 doc for more details.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but it doesn't exactly answer my question. The problem is the second part : updating my Episode field with the selected Serie Id. I was doing it with AJAX requests, but i need to know if there's a simpler way to do it.

Comment: What if you fetch only the Episodes you need with the query above before you render the form ? `return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')->where('e.serieId = serie.id');` If you need to update your Episode field dynamically on Serie field change, you have to use the same query with Ajax indeed.

Comment: Well ok, i will try with this query. I wanted to avoid ajax, but i think it will not be only an option...
Thank you !